# Time complexity of a function calling another function twice to compare contents of two lists

Tags: python, time, complexity-theory

Time complexity problem for 'equal' method:

```
def thing(l, pos):
    c = 0
    for index in range(0, len(l)):
        if index == l[index]:
             c += 1
    return c

def equal(l, l2):
    for i in range(0, len(l)):
         if thing(l, i) != thing(l2, i):
         return False
    return True

   l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
   l2 = [1, 2, 3, 5]
   test = equal(l1, l2)
   print(test)
```

I am trying to figure out the time complexity of the equal method.  The equal method has a for loop to iterate through the length of one list, which is O(n) time complexity.  What I am unsure of, though, is what the time complexity of function is when the method 'thing' is called for the first list and the second list.  Any thoughts on the time complexity of the overall 'equal' method?

Comment: Hi  simulated_mand! Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: It seems like in your code `ele` is never defined

Comment: it seems like it would be O(n^3), because for every loop through l (n) it loops through l again (n^2) and l2 again (n^3)

Comment: Just a typo there - corrected!

Comment: @Mark no. Because that would be (2n)^2 -> 4n^2 -> O(N^2)